# How to I test for a pattern in xslt and then hide the output?

Tags: xslt

I'm using xslt to create onscreen pdf's from xml and I need to hide an xref but only when it appears within a title element.

For example:

```
<title><i>Naseem Akhtar v Birmingham City Council</i> [2011] EWCA Civ 383 <xref href="#Public_PUBLICLAW_PLLR_2011PLLR002">Click here for transcript</xref></title>
```

Here I would want to just display

```
Naseem Akhtar v Birmingham City Council</i> [2011] EWCA Civ 383
```

The value "Click here for transcript" remains contstant

I have tried the following wild stabs in the dark:

```
<xsl:template match="title">
 <xsl:if test="xref=href">
  <fo:block
    font-weight="bold"
    text-transform="uppercase">

    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </fo:block>
 </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

and also

```
<xsl:template match="title">
    <xsl:if test="*[contains(@class,' topic/xref ')][not(@href='')]">
  <fo:block
    font-weight="bold"
    text-transform="uppercase">

     <xsl:apply-templates />

  </fo:block>
   </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

but neither catch the xref.

Could someone please point me in the right direction please.

Thanks.

Comment: Good question, +1. Just provide an empty template matching `title/xref`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This short and simple transformation** (no conditionals at al and only a single template):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="title/xref"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<title>
    <i>Naseem Akhtar v Birmingham City Council</i> [2011] EWCA Civ 383 
    <xref href="#Public_PUBLICLAW_PLLR_2011PLLR002">Click here for transcript</xref>
</title>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
Naseem Akhtar v Birmingham City Council [2011] EWCA Civ 383
```

**Explanation**:

1. If no templates are specified, an XSLT processor uses the **[built-in XSLT templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#built-in-rule)** and the summary result of doing so is outputting all text nodes in document order.
2. We alter the effect of 1. above by overriding the built-in template that matches any element -- for any `xref` element that is a child of `title`. The overriding template has empty body, which in effect "deletes" the content of this element.

Comment: Thanks Dimitre, a very simple answer. But, I am in idiot and just realised that I didn't want to match the title/xref but this line: <p outputclass="LC LRCaseName"><i>Naseem Akhtar v Birmingham City Council</i> [2011] EWCA Civ 383 <xref href="#Public_PUBLICLAW_PLLR_2011PLLR002">Click here for transcript</xref></p>

Comment: and am now trying: <xsl:template match="p[@outputclass='LC LRCaseName']/xref"/>

Comment: @HedleyPhillips: No problem, just replace in my solution `<xsl:template match="title/xref"/>` with `<xsl:template match="p/xref"/>`

Comment: ah, I had thought of that (which for me is a minor miracle) but we have other xrefs in other p template matches so it has to be specific to the output class. Sorry to be making what was such a quick reply into something complicated.

Comment: @HedleyPhillips: In this case it is better to ask a new question and to describe the situation more completely. The comments give us only a limited way to do this.

Comment: Ok, new and hopefully correct question asked... thanks for your help again.